# Find uniqueness in rows with NA?

Tags: r, dataframe, unique, uniqueidentifier, unique-constraint

I have a data frame like below. I would like to find unique rows (uniqueness rows).

But in this data I have 'NA' as missing data. So, NA can get any value like other rows. Fore example: in row c6, it is possible NA get 0,1 or 2 in column a2, or in row c8 it is possible NA get 0 or 1 in column a3.

In the other hand, in rows 1 ,2 and 6 all values except NA are the same so because NA can be value '0 or 1', I like to remove this row and just keep row 2.

Also, in row c6, columns a1 and a3(exclude NA columns) are the same as row c2 and c5 and there is possible NAs in c6 get same value like as c2 and c5, so this row is not unique.

data:

```
      a1  a2   a3   a4
c1    2    1    0   NA
c2    2    1    0    0
c3    2    1    1    0
c4    2    2    0   NA
c5    2    1    0    0
c6    2    NA   0   NA
c7    1    NA   0   NA
c8    2    0   NA   NA
```

I would like to have this output:

output:

```
     a1    a2  a3   a4
c2    2    1    0    0
c3    2    1    1    0
c4    2    2    0   NA
c7    1    NA   0   NA
c8    2    0   NA   NA
```

Also, @ Sotos solution help me more but in last part after removing NA when make pattern for rows , his solution consider same pattern (23) for c8 and c6 and remove them. But actually c8 is unique.Also, C7 is unique but ignore it.

```
c1 <- c( 2,1,0,NA)
c2<-c( 2,1,0,0)
c3<-c(2,1,1,0)
c4<-c(2, 2,0,NA)
c5<-c( 2,1,0,0)
c6<-c(2,NA,0,NA)
c7<-c(1,NA,0,NA)
c8 <-c(2,0,NA,NA)

df<-as.data.frame(rbind(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8))

library(stringr) 

df <- unique(df)
df$new <- apply(df, 1, function(i) paste(na.omit(i), collapse = ''))
df$new2 <- rowSums(sapply(df$new, function(i) str_detect(i, df$new)))
new_df <- subset(df, df$new2 == 1)
new_df <- new_df[, !names(new_df) %in% c('new', 'new2')]
new_df
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not an R style solution and probably slow when applied to bigger data frames...

```
uniq = F
i = 1
while(!uniq){
  to.remove = vector()
  for(j in setdiff(1:nrow(df), i)){ # setdiff avoid i and j beeing identical
    row.idx = intersect(which(!is.na(df[i, ])), # get all indices which not NA
                        which(!is.na(df[j, ]))  # in both columns
    )
    if(all(df[i, row.idx] == df[j, row.idx])) # match the rows, only using the
      to.remove = union(to.remove, j)         # columns identified before
  }
  if(length(to.remove) == 0){
    uniq = T
  } else {
    df = df[-to.remove,]
    i = i + 1
  }
}
```

Comment: @ mariodeng: thanks a lot for your solution. it is work good but , I would like row c2 instead of c1. can you help me in this regards?

Comment: Whats the criterion on how to decide which one to keep/remove?

Comment: I prefer keep row with value, when I have two rows that one of them is include NA (like row c1 and c2). It is more informative for my future analysis. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Just check which one hast less `NA` elements in it ;)

Comment: @ Dear mariodeng: do you have any solution for below data.Because you solotion did not work for it.c1<-c(0,1,2,1,NA,1,0)
c2<-c(1,1,2,1,NA,1,0)
c3<-c(0,1,2,1,2,1,0)
c4<-c(0,1,NA,1,NA,1,0)
c5<-c(0,1,NA,2,NA,1,0)
c6<-c(0,1,NA,2,NA,NA,0)